# Expanding multivariate Gaussian exponential term

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-distributions

I am working on a detection theory assignment, related to Gaussian distributions.

There is some linear algebra involved that somewhat confuses me.

Starting with the Gaussian PDF,
\begin{equation} 
p({x}) = \frac{1} {(2\pi)^{N/2} \sqrt{det(C)}} exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}({x} - {h})^TC^{-1}({x} - {h})\right]
\end{equation}
where $C$ is the covariance matrix, and ${x}$ and ${h}$ are vectors.
For the problem I am working on, I take the log-likelihood ratio and end up with

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{2}({x} - {h})^TC^{-1}({x} - {h})
\end{equation}

Expanding this results in
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\left({x}^TC^{-1}{x} - {x}^TC^{-1}{x} + {h}^TC^{-1}{h}
\right) + \frac{1}{2}(h^TC^{-1}x + x^TC^{-1}h)
\end{equation}

For some reason, which is unclear to me,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}(h^TC^{-1}x + x^TC^{-1}h) = x^TC^{-1}h
\end{equation}

What steps are taken or theorems are used to arrive at $x^TC^{-1}h$?

Comment: Since $C$ is symmetric, $h^TC^{-1}x=(h^TC^{-1}x)^T=x^TC^{-1}h$